# org-mode with variable content

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way in org-mode to have variable blocks of text. That is, to select between different bodies of inline text and examples, on the basis of a variable defined earlier.

I'm trying to create a tutorial for carrying out a task using two similar programs, using a single document and varying small parts of the explanation and the examples according to which program I want to export for.

I would have used `\ifthenelse{}{}{}` in LaTeX in the past, but I can't find a clean way to do this with `org-mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for drawers. Here is an example org-file you can use to choose the PROG-A text or the PROG-B text on export. You just change the string in the options line, then export to the format you want.

```
#+options:  d:("PROG-A")

If you wrap conditional text in drawers you can specify which ones are exported.

:PROG-A:
Use this for program A
:END:

:PROG-B:
Use this for program B
:END:

:PROG-A:
Use other option for program A
:END:

:PROG-B:
Use this other option program B
:END:
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. And by manipulating the "d" option via the org-export-with-drawers variable, I can generate the two output files from the command line.